# Is there a programmatic way to prevent Roku to go to screen saver mode?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on an application that waits for some time (several hours) and then play some videos and then wait again and then play videos again and so on.

Whether it is time to play content or it is time to wait is decided by the web service that provides the content to be played. In case, web service sends the signal that it is time to wait then my app pings the server every five minutes until it is time to play content.

The problem is while waiting and pinging Roku goes to screen saver mode. In the screen saver mode when the app pings server again screen saver jerks at first couple of requests (each request after 5 minutes) and then at next request Roku crashes and I have to restart the device.

So if there is a programmatic way to prevent Roku to go to screen saver mode? I am also showing a 300 seconds count down while waiting it goes in the background too when screen saver starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simulate remote button press to keep the player awake. See [Roku forums](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=71670) for discussion.